# Is there a way to convert list of values in Pandas DataFrame row to multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a list of values in a Dataframe row into seperate columns

I have tried to use pivot,pivot_table and get_dummies but I couldnt get the expected result.

Actual Columns:

```
A      B

1  [1, 3, 5]
2  [2, 4, 6]
```

Expected Output:

```
 A B_1 B_2 B_3

 1  1   3   5
 2  2   4   6
```

Comment: `df[['A']].join(pd.DataFrame(df.B.tolist(),columns=[f'B_{i+1}' for i in range(df.B.str.len().max())]))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
df_out = df.set_index('A').explode('B')
df_out = df_out.set_index(df_out.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1, append=True).unstack()
df_out.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
df_out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   A B_1 B_2 B_3
0  1   1   3   5
1  2   2   4   6
```